# Jquery UI autocomplete not working in android webview for phone with low resolution

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview, autocomplete

I am using Jquery UI for autocoomplete

1:-Its working fine in every browser including IE, Chrome, Firefox.
2:-Its Working fine on android phone with high reolution
3:-Its working fine even on low reolution in browser
4:-But its not working on webview of android

When i first click then it doesnt work after click on 3-4 times it close the select of Autocomplete work get hidden [image]

Selected but autocomplete doesnt closed.

Html:-

```
<div class="form-group" id="placecatdiv">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="appendPlacesCatName">
</div>
```

JS Code:-

```
$("#appendPlacesCatName").autocomplete({
    source: newGeofenceArray,
    appendTo: "#placecatdiv",
    focus: function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding autocomplete="on"

```
<div class="form-group" id="placecatdiv">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="on" class="form-control" 
        id="appendPlacesCatName">
</div>
```